# Update two arrays in Fortran as in this C++ function

Tags: c++, reference, matrix, fortran

I have a C++ function which updates 2 arrays, with the arrays passed by reference:

```
double* CPPF(double array[],int size, double a1[], double a2[]){
    int m = size, n = size
    /* code that updates a1 and a2 arrays goes here */
    return 0;
}
```

In my main function I have

```
var bigArray = new double[size*size];

for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++){
   for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
       bigArray[i * size + j] = bigArray [j * size+ i] = Other[i,j];
}

double[] a1 = new double[size * size];
double[] a2 = new double[size];

double* RESULT = CPPF(bigArray, size, a1, a2);

// Use updated a1 and a2
```

How would I define a Fortran function that updates these 2 arrays? I know that is possible because you do not pass arguments by values, only by reference.

I have so far tried something like:

```
REAL FUNCTION  FF(A, size, a1,a2)
   IMPLICIT  NONE
   INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: size
   REAL :: A(:,:), a1(:),a2(:)
   !UPDATE a1 and a2 and finish   
END FUNCTION  FF
```

Comment: In your statement "I know that is possible because you do not pass arguments by values, only by reference", do you mean that in Fortran you do not pass things by values? In Fortran, it is up to the compiler writer what they do in their implementation. The Fortran standard doesn't say whether or not arguments are passed by reference or by value.

Comment: `Other[i,j]` is equivalent to `Other[j]`. You probably want `Other[i][j]` or something instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a translation including allocations:

```
module arrays_module
  implicit none
  ! Define a kind parameter for double precision real numbers.
  integer, parameter :: rk = selected_real_kind(16)

  subroutine CPPF(array, a1, a2)
    ! Use assumed shape arrays
    real(kind=rk) :: array(:)
    real(kind=rk) :: a1(:)
    real(kind=rk) :: a2(:)
    integer :: m, n

    ! Use the size of the arrays
    m = size(a2)
    n = size(a2)

    ! Do the setting of your arrays...
  end subroutine CPPF
end module arrays_module

program main
  use arrays_module
  implicit none

  integer :: dimension, n
  real(kind=rk) :: bigArray(:)
  real(kind=rk) :: a1(:), a2(:)
  real(kind=rk) :: Other(dimension, dimension)

  ! Allocating the arrays dynamically
  allocate(bigArray(n*n))
  allocate(a1(n*n))
  allocate(a2(n))

  do i=1,dimension
    do j=1,i
      bigArray((i-1)*n + j) = Other(i,j)
      bigArray((j-1)*n + i) = Other(i,j)
    end do
  end do

  call CPPF(array = bigArray, a1 = a1, a2 = a2)
  ! Use the updated arrays...
end program main
```

You could also have CPPF allocate the new arrays for you, if this is desirable.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing looks almost fine. Note only that Fortran's `real` is a single-precision float, an analog of `C`'s `float` type.

I'm not sure what is the return value of your function. In Fortran you typically use `subroutine`s if you don't return anything:

```
subroutine  FF(A, size1, a1,a2)
   IMPLICIT  NONE
   INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: size1
   REAL*8, dimension(size1), intent(inout) :: A(size1,size1), a1(size1),a2(size1)

   A(1,1) = a1(1)*a2(1)

END subroutine FF


program blah
implicit none
 real*8 :: A(3,3), a1(3), a2(3)

 a1(1)=3.d0; a2(1)=2.d0;

 call ff(A,3,a1,a2)

 print*, A

end program blah
```

Comment: And  how would you call it from fortran main, where do you allocate the sizes?

Comment: See the edited answer. Here I'm allocating everything in the main. You can allocate things in the subroutine if you want to.